# Eclipse alt+shift+l conflict with window shortcut

Tags: eclipse, windows

[image]
I installed windows 10 a week ago. When I try to use shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> in eclipse it works, but it also open the window in the screenshot. How can I disable this combination for OS (because I don't use it and it is not convinient to open every time when I use this combination in eclipse)? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem! pls share the answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't have it. :(

Comment: I share the solution:  how to disable  a general Alt Shift L consequence created by Synaptics touchpad

• Open a command prompt with administrator privileges.  To do this, right-click Start and select Command Prompt (Admin).
• Type the following as a single line into the command prompt window and press Enter:

reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SynTP\Parameters\Debug /v DumpKernel /d 00000000 /t REG_DWORD /f
 

more info:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/touchpad-driver-diagnostic-pop-up/f8ad5ca2-9559-4327-9b7e-bdaaaca4d2b1?page=3

Comment: Great, this working like a charm :). Thank you very much ! Just to mention that, after typing this in the cmd you should restart your computer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As described in [this answer on the Microsoft website](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/touchpad-driver-diagnostic-pop-up/f8ad5ca2-9559-4327-9b7e-bdaaaca4d2b1):

- Open a command prompt with administrator privileges.  To do this, right-click Start and select Command Prompt (Admin).
- Type the following as a single line into the command prompt window and press Enter:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\SynTP\Parameters\Debug /v DumpKernel /d 00000000 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

- Reboot the computer.

Comment: exactly what is this command supposed to do? what am i changing when i run it? :\

Comment: @GianMarcoGherardi that *might* be the net effect of the change, but that space in the registry seems an odd place for synaptics to keep a setting like that (also, since it's hosted in CurrentControlSet, doesn't that mean it breaks when i change my hardware config?)  also, running the command does nothing for me, (the damn popup keeps showing up even after a reboot) and this is the only "solution" i keep finding everywhere for this problem.

Comment: Actually, i just checked. the drivers were updated and now the registry key appears to be gone.

Comment: Applying this *after* the update did work, but i bet the problems will return once i install a new update. thanks anyways.

Comment: Update : yup. They're back. I guess i sould just run that conmand at boot via script. 2016 everyone.

Comment: @TimothyGroote 2018 and we're still stuck in the past